# Exclude delimiter with csplit

Tags: csplit

Is it possible to remove the delimiter with csplit? Example:

```
$ cat in
abc
---
def
---
ghi
$ csplit -q in /-/ '{*}'
$ ls x*
xx00  xx01  xx02
$ head xx*
==> xx00 <==
abc

==> xx01 <==
---
def

==> xx02 <==
---
ghi
```

Instead of what it did, i.e. split and keep the delimiter, can it be asked to split and remove the delimiter?

That is, the desired output would be this:

```
$ sed -i '/-/d' xx*
$ head xx*
==> xx00 <==
abc

==> xx01 <==
def

==> xx02 <==
ghi
```

While it can be done in two steps as above, can it be done in one step?

If it cannot be done with csplit, is there a one-step way that is shorter compared to the two invocations (csplit + sed) above? No preference to a tool used as long as it's reasonably readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make do with a string match rather than a regex match

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="---\n"; ORS=""} {print > sprintf("xx%02d", NR)}' in
```

With GNU awk (at least in v4.0.1) it *is* possible to use a regex for `RS` e.g.

```
gawk 'BEGIN {RS="-+\n"; ORS=""} {print > sprintf("xx%02d", NR)}' in
```

Comment: Thanks +1, I can actually, though is there a short way to do partial string match instead of using RS and supplying the whole one? The separator is like 50 characters...

Comment: @levantpied see edit - it may be possible, if you have the GNU version of awk

Comment: Nice! I can confirm this works in gawk 3.1.7.

Answer (score 7):

Since you seem to be using `gnu csplit`, it's quite simple:

```
csplit --suppress-matched infile /PATTERN/ '{*}'
```

i.e. use `--suppress-matched` to suppress the lines matching `PATTERN`.

---

Per your note, this option is available only with more recent versions of `csplit` (`coreutils` ≥ 8.22)

Comment: Ha! The distribution that I'm on uses coreutils 8.4 (yes, ancient), which looks like it doesn't support that option... It was added in 2013: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=4114c93af398d7aecb5eb253f90d9b4cc0785643, so that was included in 8.22. Thanks for the hint though, will become useful with the upgrade I guess!

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $fnum=0; open $fh, ">", sprintf "xx%02d", $fnum++ } if (m/-/) { open $fh, ">", sprintf "xx%02d", $fnum++ } else { print $fh $_ }' inputfileorfileshere
```

Or a similar reopen-into-new-file-on-matching-appropriate-line via `awk` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks +1, quite long one-liner though :)

Comment: +1 , by far the best answer here. Worked better and quicker than csplit for me.